# Python BSoup extracting href text

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am writing some Python to scrape lottery numbers and a other columns in a table.

The issue I have is trying to extract January 2001 in the following [January 2001](/results/2001/january) using Python and BeautifulSoup.

The code I have created so far

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.lotterysearch.org/results/2001"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1 Safari/605.1.15"
}
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

table = soup.find("table", {"style": "width:100%"})
# Get each table row 'tr'
for row in table.find_all("tr"):

    cells = row.findAll("td")

    # print(row.find("td").find("a"))
    draw_year = cells[0].find("a")
    draw_date = cells[0].find(text=True)

    #   draw_date = cells[0].find(text=True)
    winning_numbers = cells[1].find(text=True)
    jackpot = cells[3].find(text=True)
    draw_number = cells[4].find(text=True)

    print(draw_year)
```

The results that get printed are

[January 2001](/results/2001/january)

I could do some sub stringing to pull out the January 2001 but want to find the correct method for doing so.

Comment: Do you want to extract the value from the attribute `href` or from within the content of the tag ? `draw_year.string` should get you the value from within the tag. `draw_year['href']` should get you the value from the attribute

Comment: it is the actual value between the tags so January 2001

Answer (score 1):

I made this quick change. Please let me know if it is helpful. I think it prints a relative URL but you can combine it with the base URL.

```
draw_year = cells[0].find("a", href=True)

if draw_year is not None:
        print(draw_year['href'])
```

Comment: This does the same as what I have already, it is the January 2001 that I want to extract from the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I got it now. Add this to the end. I added the if statement because you get a None type in the output. Is this how you want it?

```
if draw_year is not None:
    print(draw_year.get_text()
```

Comment: I tried this but did not get it work, It did point me in the right direction though thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that I was not catering for `None` when trying to extract the `.text` so I tested for None if `type(draw_year) != type(None)`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.lotterysearch.org/results/2001"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1 Safari/605.1.15"
}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

table = soup.find("table", {"style": "width:100%"})
# Get each table row 'tr'
for row in table.find_all("tr"):

    cells = row.findAll("td")

    draw_year = cells[0].find("a")
    draw_date = cells[0].find(text=True)

    #   draw_date = cells[0].find(text=True)
    winning_numbers = cells[1].find(text=True)
    jackpot = cells[3].find(text=True)
    draw_number = cells[4].find(text=True)

    if type(draw_year) != type(None):
        print(draw_year.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you can also use:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
h = { "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1 Safari/605.1.15"}
u = "https://www.lotterysearch.org/results/2001"
html = requests.get(u, headers=h).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", {"style": "width:100%"})
for row in table.find_all("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("td")
    draw_year = cells[0].findAll("a")
    if not len(draw_year) == 1: continue  # skip 1st tr that only contains Date
    draw_year = draw_year[0].text
    draw_date = cells[0].find(text=True)
    winning_numbers = cells[1].find(text=True)
    jackpot = cells[3].find(text=True)
    draw_number = cells[4].find(text=True)
    print(draw_year)
```

---

```
January 2001
January 2001
January 2001
January 2001
January 2001
January 2001
January 2001
...
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/8d70aa2688)